# Virtual function overloading in diamond hierarchy produces different results in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, overloading, language-lawyer

The following code produces different results on clang.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy1 {};
struct Dummy2 {};

struct A {
    virtual void foo(Dummy1) {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void foo(Dummy2) {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};


template<class T>
struct C : virtual A {
    using A::foo;
    void foo(Dummy2) override {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }   
};


template<class T>
struct B : virtual A {
    using A::foo;
    void foo(Dummy1) final {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }   
};

template<class T>
struct D : B<T>, C<T> {
    // using B<T>::foo; // error: call to member function 'foo' is ambiguous
    // using C<T>::foo; // error: call to member function 'foo' is ambiguous
    using A::foo;
};


int main() {
    D<int> d;
    d.foo(Dummy1{});
    d.foo(Dummy2{});

    A& a = d;
    a.foo(Dummy1{});
    a.foo(Dummy2{});

    B<int>& b = d;
    b.foo(Dummy1{});
    b.foo(Dummy2{});


    C<int>& c =d;
    c.foo(Dummy1{});
    c.foo(Dummy2{});

    return 0;
}
```

gcc (versions 4.8.1 - 9.1), icc (versions 16, 17, 19), Visual Studio 2017 15.4.0 Preview 1.0, Visual Studio 2013 12.0.31101.00 Update 4, clang (versions 3.4.1 - 3.9.1)

All give the following output, which is what I expect:

```
B
C
B
C
B
C
B
C
```

Only methods `C<T>::foo(Dummy1)` and `B<T>::foo(Dummy2)` are selected, methods `A<T>::foo` are not used.

Clang (versions 4.0.0 - 8.0.0) selects `A::foo(Dummy2)` when called through `D<T>` object and only then. When called through reference to `B<T>` - `C<T>::foo(Dummy2)` is selected.

```
B
A <-- difference
B
C
B
C
B
C
```

When the order of the derived classes is changed to `struct D : C<T>, B<T>`, then output changes to:

```
A <--
C
B
C
B
C
B
C
```

It seems that for second derived class method `foo` is not considered virtual.

Only Visual Studio is giving warning with not that helpful [C4250](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4250).

Writing `using B<T>::foo;` and `using C<T>::foo;` in `D<T>` instead of `using A::foo;` makes clang produce the following error:

> error: call to member function 'foo' is ambiguous

On gcc behavior doesn't change, code compiles and output is the same.

What is correct behavior here?

Since application gives different results, is there a way to find all similar instances of this construction or make some workaround? I have to compile with both gcc and clang. Checking if same problem is present in more places than I found can be hard.

Comment: For the program shown, clang is definitely buggy. For the version with two `using` declarations in `D`, [\[namespace.udecl\]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#15) is far from clear about what happens. Are members from a previous _using-declarator_ "in the derived class"?

Comment: I also think it is a clang bug; selecting `A::foo` via unqualified function call should not disable virtual dispatch

Comment: Here's another test case that doesn't use function overloading https://wandbox.org/permlink/NGGfh7OOnRveO2zN the functions overrides seem to be ignored unless they're in the first inherited node, but they work fine if you don't have the `using` or you're using a reference to the base class.

Comment: I added bug report to clang's issue tracker https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42211.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two things happening here.

Firstly, there is definitely an issue with clang's implementation, so filing a bug report is a good move.

But there's an issue as well when you call foo on a `D` reference

```
D<int> d;
d.foo(Dummy1{});
d.foo(Dummy2{});
```

The warning visual studio gives you is actually very accurate: there are technically two options in each call, but one gets chosen over the other through *dominance*.

For the `Dummy1` overload there's the overridden implementation in class `B`, but also the *not-overridden* implementation from class `C`. This is what the warning refers to as the "dominant" one hiding the other one. 
The dominant version in this case is the overridden version in class `B` while the weak one is the one from class `C`. If you'd overwritten the `Dummy1` overload in class `C` as well, you would have had an ambiguous call.

The analogous is true for the `Dummy2` overload.

So what the compiler is warning you about is that in the case of a known `D` instance, you actually have a choice and should be explicit about it.